# Reading the remaining content of the serial buffer Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I have a program that involves continuous reading of the serial port and then doing some processing. Due to the processing, I have some delay in reading the values (I read line by line). Once the user presses stop, the reading stops and I wan't to make sure that the buffer is fully read. I know that there will be some data in the buffer and I don't want to loose it once the comport is closed. is there a way to read the content of the whole buffer at once?

I tried fscanf(comport) but it only read one element.

I know fread reads the whole buffer, but I don't know how to convert the binary to string and get my useful data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can read all by fread, then it is just a matter of formatting. You could fread all as number, and convert to char:

```
u8 = fread(comport, comport.BytesAvailable); % uchar, but in double 
ch = char(u8);
```

This should give you all in buffer as string.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got the following error "Error using serial/fread (line 134)
SIZE cannot be set to INF." why is that? does it refer to the size of my buffer?

Comment: I substituted (inf) with the number of bytes available and got an error in the precision so I changed it to just 'char'. What I got was a stream of numbers that do not look like my typical data. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Sorry *fread/serial* does not support those parameter for file *fread*. The bytes input must be greater than 0, and can not be inf. I just updated the answer using *BytesAvailable* as you noted. You may need to check if *BytesAvaible* is 0 to avoid error.